# Cumulative sum with `all` or `any` by group

Tags: r, vector, cumsum

Consider the vectors

```r
group = rep(1:6, each = 2)
x = 1:12
```

Now, I wanna compute a cumulative sum by group if any of the members of the group meets a condition. The condition is, e.g, that `x %% 3 == 0`.

```r
## Without the cumulative sum
ave(x, group, FUN = function(x) any(x %% 3 == 0)) 
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1

## With the cumulative sum
ave(x, group, FUN = function(x) cumsum(any(x %% 3 == 0)))
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1

##Expected result with cumsum:
# [1] 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2
```

This also arises in `dplyr`:

```r
dWithoutCumsum <- data.frame(group, x) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(z = +any(x %% 3 == 0))

dWithCumsum <- data.frame(group, x) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(z = cumsum(any(x %% 3 == 0)))

all.equal(dWithCumsum,dWithoutCumsum)
# [1] TRUE
```

Moreover, when the `cumsum` function is set afterwards, everything's alright:

```r
ave(ave(x, group, FUN = function(x) any(x %% 3 == 0)), group, FUN = cumsum)
# [1] 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2

data.frame(group, x) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(z = any(x %% 3 == 0),
         z = cumsum(z)) %>% 
  pull(z)
# [1] 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2
```

Why is it the case that the `cumsum` function does not work as expected in those cases (does not work with `all` instead of `any` as well), and is it possible to get the expected result in one line?

Comment: The `any()` function returns a scalar, so `cumsum(any(...))` is just the same as `any(...)`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a way to avoid two commands to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually doing a `cumsum`--nothing needs to be summed. You are looking for the row number within the group.

Here are a couple ways with `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    result1 = row_number() * any(y %% 3 == 0),
    result2 = case_when(
      any(y %% 3 == 0) ~ row_number(),
      TRUE ~ 0L
    )
  )
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
# # Groups:   group [6]
#    group     y result1 result2
#    <int> <int>   <int>   <int>
#  1     1     1       0       0
#  2     1     2       0       0
#  3     2     3       1       1
#  4     2     4       2       2
#  5     3     5       1       1
#  6     3     6       2       2
#  7     4     7       0       0
#  8     4     8       0       0
#  9     5     9       1       1
# 10     5    10       2       2
# 11     6    11       1       1
# 12     6    12       2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to return an increasing sequence if you detect at least one multiple of 3 and a zero vector otherwise. In that case:

```r
g <- gl(6, 2)
g
##  [1] 1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6
## Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6

x <- seq_along(g)
x
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

f <- function(x) if (any(x %% 3 == 0)) seq_along(x) else integer(length(x))

unsplit(tapply(x, g, f, simplify = FALSE), g)
## [1] 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2
```

Or, within a data frame, with `dplyr`:

```r
library("dplyr")
d <- data.frame(g, x)
d %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(y = f(x))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
# Groups:   g [6]
   g         x     y
   <fct> <int> <int>
 1 1         1     0
 2 1         2     0
 3 2         3     1
 4 2         4     2
 5 3         5     1
 6 3         6     2
 7 4         7     0
 8 4         8     0
 9 5         9     1
10 5        10     2
11 6        11     1
12 6        12     2
```